# How to insert word in nth line of a file

Tags: unix

Is there a way to add a string in a specific line in a file and if something else is there replace it?

eg

command "HELLO" nth_line  file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute "HELLO" in `filename` at line 2

```
awk 'NR==2{gsub(/.*/, "HELLO")}1' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
sed '42s/.*/something else/'
```

However this won't work if the file fewer than 42 lines.